# How to search a value of a Child in Firebase

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an Android App in which I have created a Login page. Where user will enter his username and password. Now How can I search wether that username with same password is present in my Firebase database.

Here is my Firebase Database Structure:

[image]

There are several methods on Internet but those are not working for me because those methods requires exact child name as an input before search. But in my case, I have randomly generated keys under Admin and Employees section. How can I search for name and Password using user's input username and password fields. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to query across `ZXMU5741/ADMIN` and `ZXMU5741/Employees` at the same time. You will need to execute two queries, one on `ZXMU5741/ADMIN` and one on `ZXMU5741/Employees`. Each of those can them use the same basic approach:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ZXMU5741/ADMIN");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo("haseeb");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            long password = userSnapshot.child("password").getValue(Long.class);
            if (password == 41231) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```